# How to place a css button in center (horizontal) of four table columns

Tags: html, forms, css, css-tables

I have a home search form on frontpage of my website [tjsoldit.com](http://tjsoldit.com). The form is not coded by me, it is provided by my home search real estate company and I embedded it by inserting the two line script calling the form. I can only set some custom css rules for form in my custom css sheet as I am provided with css classes of the different elements of the form. The form is  is rendered in a table with rows for all the search fields and their matching labels. The structure of the form can be seen here http://tjsoldit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/4-columns.jpg .

As you can see in the structure, the button is an element of first column of the form. All I want is to center the button so that the button will come in the horizontal center of its line (almost half under column 2 and half under column 3). I have tried all display properties like `display:inline;`,`display:table` etc. But not able to do so. Please help.

The css class of search button is: `.ds-quick-search-button`, class of form fields is `.ds-quick-search-name` and class of field values is `.ds-quick-search-name` and more about the structure of form is can be read here: www.diversesolutions.com/design-tips/idx-quick-search-styling-guide-6744

NOTE: I am provided with just an embedding code. So cannot change html. I can just play with its css.

Comment: did you try `colspan="4"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `colspan="4"` (merging of 4 cells) and `align="center"`

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center">
<input type="button" value="Search" class="ds-quick-search-button">
</td>
</tr>
```

**OR**

Create an outer div to your table and add the table style to the outer div, increase the padding values `padding: 6px 24px 36px 24px;`

and then try adding this

```
.ds-quick-search tr:last-child input{margin:2% 0 0 25%; position:absolute; }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/CBmmt/)**

---

To give space between column 1 & 2 and between 3 & 4

```
.ds-quick-search td:first-child{padding-right:15px}
.ds-quick-search td:nth-child(3){padding-right:15px}
```

Comment: But I cannot edit its HTML. As, I have only provided with a code/script to embed the form. So please tell how to do this in css.

Comment: Centered but it went out of form. See rightt now at my homepage

Comment: to solve Sowmya's solution, you should add a position: relative to the parent element of the button

Comment: @Mark that didnt work. I have updated the answer with another solution.

Comment: But again the problem is I cannot edit the HTML so how can I add this div around table in HTML?

Comment: @user2042436 dont edit that html. add that html inside the new div

Comment: Perfect. Now the second thing is I want to increase the space between column 1 & 2 and between 3 & 4 as the form field names and inputs are very close and congested. Please guide in this also

Comment: Thanks. Now as a last thing I want to change the value of button from "Search" to "Find home". Please help me in this too.

Comment: @Sowmya Thanks. Now as a last thing I want to change the value of button from "Search" to "Find home". Please help me in this too.

Comment: @user2042436 thats not possible with css

Answer (score 0):

Set marging of button `50%`, like this:

```
.ds-quick-search-button { 
   margin-left:50%;
}
```

Comment: this will move the button but the button still remains in column 1 and the width of column increases.

Comment: make `position:absolute;` and then set the margin